# Different probabilities with permutation and combination?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Two fair 6-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that both dice show the same number?

Number of ways to get the same number on both dice is 6. Total possible **combinations** of dice roll is $\frac{6 \cdot 6}{2} = 18$. Hence the answer is $\frac{6}{18} = \frac{1}{3}$.

But I get a different answer when I compare number of ways to get the same number on both dice to the total possible **permutations** of dice rolls. Total permutations of dice roll are $6 \cdot 6 = 36$. Hence the probability is $\frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}$.

Why do I get different answers? When to use

$$\frac{\text{Successful permutations}}{\text{Total permutations}}$$

and when to use

$$\frac{\text{Successful combinations}}{\text{Total combinations}}$$

Comment: Use permutations in this one, $\frac{1}{6}$ is correct

Comment: To sharpen your intuition: first throw a die. Let's say it gives $5$. Then throw the second die. What is the probability that it gives a $5$ too?

Comment: Oh I got it. The rolls should be considered distinct and independent to be sure about the answer. Thanks a lot for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case the dies are not distinguishable, but in the second case they are.

Comment: How should I figure if the dice are distinguishable or not?

Comment: It depends on the context of the problem. If you play gammon they are not distinguishsble. If you roll one die twise and write down the points in the order you get them the dies are distinguishable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This cleared the doubts.